# Error running sample code using Spooky.js

Tags: node.js, webkit, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I am new to the whole stack of `node.js`, `phantom.js`, `casper.js` and `spooky.js`. I have everything installed (in Windows), with PATH updated and followed this example:

https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS

I got this error:

```
C:\node_modules\spooky>node examples/hello.js

events.js:68
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 127
    at Spooky._spawnChild.Spooky._instances.(anonymous function) (C:\node_module
s\spooky\lib\spooky.js:82:17)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
```

Anyone has any clue why and how to fix it? I run `casperjs googlelinks.js` just fine. But with `node.js` and `spooky.js`, it gave me trouble.

Comment: Have a look at this Bug: [node examples/hello.js does not work](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/14)

Comment: Yah I saw that github thread but look like there was no solution either.

Comment: That bug is fixed now. You can specify the command to run in the config object you pass to the Spooky constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the CasperJS Windows executable being named `casperjs.bat` instead of `casperjs`. See [this comment](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/14#issuecomment-11527568) on the bug @mike mentioned.

Unfortunately, you'll have to hack around [this bug](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/21) for the moment. I will release a fix for that this week.

Comment: This bug is fixed. You can specify the command to run when you start your Spooky instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the workaround provided by @mike and @lawnsea, which did lead me to the solution, but were not immediately clear to a beginner like me. The tip from minaki also helped me understand what to do: https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/14

**INSTALL SPOOKY.JS ON WINDOWS 7 WITH NPM**.

I'm using:

- Win7 64 bit
- Node v0.10.17
- CasperJS 1.1.0-DEV
- PhantomJS 1.9.2
- Added everything to my $PATH already

Steps:

- Fresh directory: mkdir spookytest, cd spookytest
- npm install spooky
- open spookytest\node_modules\spooky\lib\spooky.js in a text editor
- Change Line 26 (defaults.child.command) from 'casperjs' to 'casperjs.bat'
- Change Line 30 (defaults.child.transport) from 'stdio' to 'http'
- Save and go back to the spookytestdirectory
- node node_modules/spooky/examples/hello.js

--> Hello, from Spooky the Tuff Little Ghost - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Comment: Did it work for you? From what I know, Node.js cannot execute .bat in Windows.